# form submit on jquery append with getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

The `getElementByid('projectsearch'+id)` doesn't work when I click on the link. What can be done about this? As soon as it's generated, I have no idea about how to send the form - any ideas?

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; ++i) {            
    console.log(i);
    var divCreator ='';

    var str='projectsearch' + i; 

    divCreator+='<div id="grupo'+i+'">';
    divCreator+='<div>';
    divCreator+='<div id="tipo_'+i+'"></div>';
    divCreator+='<div id="tipo_arq_abajo'+i+'"></div>';
    divCreator+='</div>';
    divCreator+='<div id="fotoproyectos'+i+'" ><img src="' + data.data[i].path + '" height="128" width="160"></div>';
    divCreator+='<div id="nombreproyectos'+i+'" ><form method="post" name="projectsearch'+i+'" id="projectsearch'+ i +'" action="proyectos_arq.php">';
    divCreator+='<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('projectsearch'+id).submit()">"'+ data.data[i].projectName +'"</span>'
    divCreator+='<input name="project_id" type="hidden" id="project_id" value="' + data.data[i].projectId + '">';
    divCreator+='</form></div>';
    divCreator+='</div>';
    divCreator+='</div><br><br>';

    //$("#contiene-pro").append(divCreator);
    $("#testDiv").append(divCreator);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

i think that should be

```
document.getElementById('projectsearch'+i).submit() // not id...
```

and escape your quotes

if you are trying to submit the form that u just created...
and i cannot find "id" variable in your question...

Answer (score 1):

You create:

```
var str='projectsearch' + i;
```

Then never use it.

Later in the code you have:

```
divCreator+='<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('projectsearch'+id).submit()">"'+ data.data[i].projectName +'"</span>'
```

I think you mean for this to be:

```
divCreator+='<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById(' + str + ').submit()">"'+ data.data[i].projectName +'"</span>';
```

Which uses the `str` variable you created as the id for the `getElementById()`

Answer (score -1):

Please check in console for the corresponding div ids and try this syntax for getting the value

```
var element=  $("#projectsearch"+id);
```

or

```
var element=document.getElementById("projectsearch"+id);
```